# Websocket- advantages using subprotocol over custom one

Tags: websocket

I have multiple polling resources which I want to transform to websocket communication. What is the advantage to use websocket subprotocol as STOMP or Thrift instead of define custom protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of using an existing subprotocol is that it's already thought-out. You really don't need to work as hard and sometimes you'll be able to find a client library that already does what you need (saving you coding on the client side).

Another advantage is that using a well established standard subprotocol allows you to publish your API to third parties more easily (as they could, possibly, use existing libraries for the protocol).

Having said that, I usually don't bother. I noticed that it's super simple to use JSON "event" messages and ACK responses (similar to how socket.io formats it's messages, but using native Websockets)... It's almost a community standard sub-protocol by now, seeing as how often it's used.